# Are there any C++ STL alternatives which is bulletproof against timing attack?

Tags: timing-attack, c++, library

Just out of curiosity, I wonder if there are any packages of popular algorithm/data structures which are secure against timing attack.

I think GNU libstdc++ `std::string::compare()`, `std::unordered_map` (which employs [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing)) and so on are all vulnerable.

Comment: Alternatives exist, but they're not in the STL.

Comment: @tylerl Could you point me to some possible alternatives?  I'm not requiring strict STL-compatibility.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112952/cross-language-primitives-against-string-comparison-timing-attacks I'd very much like to know the answer to the question you posed.